# javascript regex duplicates parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace ...('2073')... with ....('2074')...
but I end up with ...(('2074'))... and I can't understand why.

Given the following javascript code:

```
var sGroupIdentifier = "2073";
var sSelectedGroupTR = "... onclick=\"MakeNewGroup('2073')\">New</a> ... ";
var rex = new RegExp("\('" + sGroupIdentifier + "'\)", "g")

sNewGroupIdentifier = "2074";
var sNewGroupTR = sSelectedGroupTR.replace(rex, "(\'" + sNewGroupIdentifier + "\')");
alert(sNewGroupTR)
```

Of course I can remove the parenthesis in the .replace but I just don't understand it. As far as I see there is a match for ('2073') and not for '2073' because I used a ( and not a \

Anyone care to explain...

Comment: If you're trying to use regex to change the evaluated function of an `onclick` attribute inside a string, you're probably doing it wrong...What's this for?

Comment: creating rows in a table on the fly, not changing the value but inserting and yes it's not the best option but given the fact that the html is created from a template language and could be scattered with markup this is a reasonable approach (imho ;-) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating the regular expression with a string literal, and so `\(` ends up being `(` to the regex compiler, not `\(`. If you want the regex compiler to see the `\`, you'll need to escape it in the string literal:

```
var rex = new RegExp("\\('" + sGroupIdentifier + "'\\)", "g");
```

One of many reasons to avoid using strings to create regular expressions where you can (but in your case, as `sGroupIdentifier` is a string, you probably can't).

Comment: argggh of course... and yes the variable directed me to a string so I must anticipate for a double eval thanx!